# solving question on recurrence relation and sumation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

> Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $x_{n + 1}^2 =6x_{n} +7$ for all $n ≥ 2$

Which one of the following is true?

$\quad(A).\space$ If $x_{2} > x_{1} > 7$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}$ is convergent

$\quad(B).\space$ If $x_{2} >  x_{1} > 7$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{x_n} $ converges

$\quad(C).\space$ If $7 > x_{2} > x_{1} > 6$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x_n}$ is convergent

$\quad(D).\space$ None of these is convergent

I tried by finding the infinite term which comes to be 7 for all x so according to me any summation will never converge as the infinite term is not approaching 0. but the answer is given as (B)

Comment: Do you know what $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to? The limit of the sequence will be the same for if $x_2>7$ and for $x_2<7$

Comment: @MatthewH. {xn} converges to 7 for all x

Comment: I agree with you, $x_n\to7$ always, so the correct answer is D, not B.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the recurrence relation $x_{n + 1}^2 =6x_{n} +7$ that $(x_n)$ does not converge to zero, that excludes (A).

Similarly, $y_n = 1/x_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation $1 + 6 y_n + 7 y_n^2$, so that $(y_n)$ does not converge to zero either. That excludes (B) and (C).

It is also correct that $(x_n)$ converges to $7$, but the exact limit is actually not needed to exclude the convergence of the series in (A), (B), or (C), only that $(x_n)$ resp. $(1/x_n)$ does not converge to zero.